# проблемы с наследованием Java

Tags: java, ооп

есть 3 класса
первый

```
    package cikloid;

public class Lesson25 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal animal =new Animal();
    Animal dog = new Animal(); // это и есть наследование
    animal.eat();
    animal.sleap();
    dog.eat();
    dog.bu();
}
} 
///второй
package cikloid;

public class Animal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("I me yeting");
    }
public void sleap() {
    System.out.println("I em Slepping");
}

}
// третий
package cikloid;

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public void bu() {
        System.out.print("I am bark");
    }
}
```

класс Dog наследник класса Animal при попытке вывести
System.out.print("I am bark");  в классе Lesson25
Эклипс выдает ошибку
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method bu() is undefined for the type Animal

```
at cikloid.Lesson25.main(Lesson25.java:Подскажите в чем проблема,вроде  все правильно
```

Comment: `Animal dog = new Animal();` так дог у вас энимал или всё же дог?

Comment: Спасибо понял в чем проблема, в моей невнимательности)

Answer (score 2):

```
Animal dog = new Dog(); // это и есть наследование
...
((Dog)dog).bu();
```